# iPhone - how to force a #define to return a double?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, inline

I have this method:

```
- (double) myMethod (double a, double b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

this method returns a double.

I am about to transform this in a #define statement, like

```
#define myMethod(a,b) (a * b)
```

is this define returning a double? I suppose so, but and if I want it to return a float?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A #define is simply text substitution, if you would write:

```
myMethod(1, 2)
```

it would expand to:

```
(1 * 2)
```

This is, clearly, an integer.

You could, write something like:

```
#define myMethod(a,b) ( (double)(a) * (double)(b) )
```

To ensure that you get a double floating-point operation.

Comment: ahhh... but I was receiving a floating point from that define. My question is if it was a double or float. Anyway, this is a good idea, to specify what each variable is. Thanks.

Comment: You will get what you put in. If you put in floats, you will get a float. If you put in doubles, you will get doubles. Again, unlike a real function, a #define is only replaces text before the actual compiler gets a chance to see the code.

Comment: On a related note, a couple of exercises for @Digital Robot and anyone else who reads this: Why `(double)(a) * (double)(b)` and not `(double)((a) * (b))`? Also, why `(double)(a) * (double)(b)` and not `(double)a * (double)b`?

Answer (score 10):

Don't do that. Simply use inline functions, like

```
static inline double MyMethod (double a, double b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

Just as fast, less headaches.